# Changeing code inside a html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a checkdate php code and I need to replace the dates with some kind of php/jscript code. Maybe some html form element, where I can insert the date how it is needed, submit it and then the date inside the file gets replaced. In this example the date inside this lines:

```
<?PHP


function isValidDate($sd, $ed, $currentDate = null)
{
    if ($currentDate === null) {
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
    }

    return ($currentDate >= $sd && $currentDate <= $ed);
}

$startDate = '2016-10-30';
$endDate   = '2016-10-31';

if (isValidDate($startDate, $endDate)) {
   header("Location: x.php");
} else {
    header("Location: y.htm");
}
?>
```

In this example in these lines

```
 $startDate = '2016-10-30';
    $endDate   = '2016-10-31';
```

the date should be replaced.

It should be possible with some kind of html5 input/form element, where someone can insert the date like

```
    <input type="text" value="XXXX-XX-XX" name="start"/>
       <input type="submit" value="startdate"/>
and <input type="text" value="XXXX-XX-XX" name="end"/>
       <input type="submit" value="enddate"/>
```

After submitting the date should be replaced via php/jscript or something like this.
Is this even possible? Can anybody push me in the right direction, maybe with some tutorial links f.e.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain better.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect you to have a go at it yourself first - try googling for tutorials. Just have a crack at it and see where you get to (do all the easy bits that you know how to do already, then google the bits you can't do yet). If it's still not working, edit your question and show us the code that you tried, and tell us the errors that you're getting, and we can help you debug it. But most importantly: tell us *what you observe* and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: @Jackowski I edited my post! @Taryn East I tried to google already but don't find any good solutions. It always refers me to the `document.write()` stuff, which doesn't fit my needs! I wouldn't ask, if I would know any possible way..

Comment: @pr0cz I'm trying to understand exactly what you mean. Are you asking how to get the dates from the inputs on a webpage to be analyzed via php to compare if they are valid dates?

Comment: @EricMayfield No. I want to replace the date inside my code, without editing the source code directly via f.e. notepad. So that someone can change it from a html/php site, without knowig where to search in the source code. And yes, I know the risks and lack of security, but there is no need for it in this case :)

Comment: `header("y.htm");` that isn't a valid syntax if you're planning to use it to redirect, unless you have a custom function of that name.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank, you, I know. I was too lazy to write it. It is just the surrounding of the problem. I will fix it for further readers :)

Comment: Thanks and you're welcome. Please be more careful, since that could have a bearing on answers given and possibly downvoted because of it. Laziness does hold certain consequences ;-)

Comment: @pr0cz *"Does this change my sourcecode of the start and enddate permanently?"* - There are a few ways to do this, with some of php's functions to write to a file, and/or to a database; what is it that you would like to do? Or is this question about having what was executed and write/echo the PHP "code" that was generated? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I simply want to overwrite the start- and enddate with new dates from the surface of another file. Maybe the php function to write a file will do it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the $_POST array.

First have a form like:

```
<form method="POST" action="your_file_name.php">
    <input type="text" name="start_date"/>
    <input type="text" name="end_date"/>
    <input type="submit" value="my_form_dates"/>
</form>
```

and then change your program to

```
<?php

  function isValidDate($sd, $ed, $currentDate = null)
  {
    if ($currentDate === null) {
      $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
    }
    return ($currentDate >= $sd && $currentDate <= $ed);
  }

  if (is_set($_POST['start_date']) && is_set($_POST['end_date'])) { 
    $startDate = $_POST['start_date'];
    $endDate   = $_POST['end_date'];
  }

  if (isValidDate($startDate, $endDate)) {
    header("Location: x.php");
  } else {
    header("Location: y.htm");
  }

?>
```

As you may see, you don't need that `value="XXXX-XX-XX"` attributes, because the values of the fields will be typed by the user at runtime.

Don't forget make `your_file_name.php` in the form match with the name of your program, be it `.php` or `.html`.

I suggest you to read more about this `$_POST` array at [this page](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php).

Comment: Thank you for your input! Does this change my sourcecode of the start and enddate permanently? Or do I just get redirected?

Comment: None of them. This won't change your code. This won't redirect you nowhere. **This will make your code flexible, by avoiding this hardcoding of two dates.** The user will input the two dates and your program will use them. Every time the form is sent your program will receive the dates typed in the form.

Comment: Ed, you left the same syntax the OP using, being `header("y.htm");`  that should have been caught and corrected. Unless the OP has a custom function of that name, but I seriously doubt that. Edit: To which the OP has responded by my comment to them up there.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida You're welcome Ed. The OP made the correction. I would also like to suggest, using a conditional statement around the POST arrays, in order to check if the submit `is set` and equal to POST, and checking if any inputs are (not) empty, if their entire code is inside the same file. Sometimes things go empty or cause errors and adding `exit;` after each header. That way it won't keep executing.

Comment: I avoided to make things more complex, @Fred-ii-. As you may notice, the OP is really newbie in PHP programming!

Comment: @EddeAlmeida True but it's part of the basics in PHP. If their code fails based on that, then they won't know what happened and how to fix it. You are right though that they're very new to coding (in php), that seeing this comment they left up there: *"Does this change my sourcecode of the start and enddate permanently?"* - This tells me that what they need is to either write it to a file, and/or to a database. I feel the question goes deeper than we've been given to know. If this is a question about "how to" do that, then they (the OP) should have been precise about this from the beginning.